# Angularjs directive remove watch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `$scope.$watch` declared in the controller of a directive. When I change pages and the directive is removed do I have to manually destroy the way? If so how do I detect when the directive has been removed?

Comment: Angular should take care of that for you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on the scope, not the directive. If the scope is destroyed, then all its $watchers die with it. On page change your scope'll be destroyed by angular, so you should be safe.

When a scope dies it yields a $destroy event. You can watch it:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', callback);
```

and you can manually detach $watchers from the scope, by calling the function it returns:

```
var sentinel = $scope.$watch('expression', callback);
sentinel(); // kill sentinel
```

You can do this with $on too.

Comment: Firstly, you said when scope is destroyed, all watchers die with it. Then you suggested manually removing watchers on scope $destroy event (why? they are supposed to automatically die with scope). That does not make sense to me. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: When the page is changed with the ngView angular will cleanup the last scope for you with the watchers. (proof => http://goo.gl/GD0pM9)
Also angular gives you a watcher destroy function so you can manually remove the expression if you don't need it anymore on the current scope.